# VueJS cannot get path after reload or direct link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have trouble with VueJS(or with my brains). Ok. I have vuejs-webpack project and this router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Main from '@/components/Main'
import CreateTravel from '@/components/CreateTravel'
import TravelDetail from '@/components/TravelDetail'
import Friends from '@/components/Friends'
import UserTravels from '@/components/UserTravels'
import User from '@/components/User'
import Settings from '@/components/Settings'
import UserActivate from '@/components/UserActivate'

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/activate/:secret',
      name: 'UserActivate',
      component: UserActivate
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Main',
      component: Main
    },
    {
      path: "/create",
      name: "Create",
      component: CreateTravel
    },
    {
      path: "/travel/:id",
      name: "Travel",
      component: TravelDetail
    },
    {
      path: "/friends",
      name: "Friends",
      component: Friends
    },
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      name: 'User',
      component: User,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'travels',
          name: 'UserTravels',
          component: UserTravels
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'Settings',
      component: Settings
    }
  ]
})
```

And main.js:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import VueResource from  'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {App}
});
```

And when I redirect to some link I have 404. Example, after redirect on link http://localhost:8080/user/activate/73e7bcfa-a9d2-4d32-8ddc-697a82bf6363 from email I look "Cannot GET /user/activate/73e7bcfa-a9d2-4d32-8ddc-697a82bf6363". In console browser next:

361d711d-05ef-4c5e-944a-7e511ba104ab:1 GET http://localhost:8080/user/activate/361d711d-05ef-4c5e-944a-7e511ba104ab 404 (Not Found). Thanks for your help

Comment: Any code for the UserActivate component?

Comment: Yes.https://pastebin.com/S2VfGWSG

Comment: @csanonymus any ideas?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Vue or javascript at all. You didn't set up your server to work with requests like this. All you need to do is to make your server respond with landing page (index.js) for every request (but static assets of course), so that Vue application can bootstrap and kick off routing. If you don't do it your only option is to use hash mode: `http://localhost:8080/#/user/activate/73e7bcfa-a9d2-4d32-8ddc-697a82bf6363`

Comment: @dfsq thanks. Hash mode works for me!